# Using regex to check corrections of input

Tags: python, regex, input

I'm trying to use regex to checking it's the same with input chars.

To be shorter, i'm writing char to the console and i need to check it with pattern. I must write for ex. 123-45-67-890 to go to the next operation. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The best questions often include some code. You may  [edit] to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for pattern you need:

```
import re
def check (s) : return False if re.match('^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}$', s )==None else True

>>> check ('123-4567-890')
False
>>> check ('123-45-67-890')
True
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great :)